# Wildfly 23 Failed to link Listener from Service module loader: Jakarta/jms/messageListener

Tags: jms, wildfly

I have an old wildfly 10 project that was in javaee 6, migrate to java 11 with wildfly 23. but it seems the listener wont load correctly in wildfly 23, recieved following error, can anyone guide me on a direction how this error is and where should I look at to solve it?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link se/uc/minuc/jms/MaintainPppListener (Module "deployment.MinUCService-ear-5.3.63-SNAPSHOT.ear.se.uc.minuc-MinUCService-rest-5.3.63-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link se/uc/minuc/jms/AbstractListener (Module "deployment.MinUCService-ear-5.3.63-SNAPSHOT.ear.se.uc.minuc-MinUCService-rest-5.3.63-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/jms/MessageListener
```

Comment: You seem to be using jakarta/jms/MessageListener while you should be using javax/jms/MessageListener as jakarta/jms/MessageListener is Jakarta EE 9 which is only supported by WildFly preview.

Comment: thank, I solved it when loading correct module org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq